# Debug CGAL example using Boost on Mac OS

Tags: debugging, boost, cgal

I have CGAL compiled manually and installed in `~/Library/CGAL/CGAL-4.0.2/`. `Boost (boost @1.50.0_0+debug+no_single+no_static)` as well as `cmake (2.8.8_1)` are installed using `macports`. For compilation purposes of the provided examples things work nicely. My problem is when I try to debug an example. In particular, for instance, I ran `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .` in the directory containing the `Arrangements_on_surfaces_2` and then `make`. The generated binary functions as expected, but when running `gdb foo` in order to debug `foo`, I get the following warnings:

```
warning: Could not find object file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_boost/boost/work/boost_1_50_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/address-model-64/architecture-x86/threading-multi/pthread/thread.o" - no debug information available for "libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp".    

warning: Could not find object file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_boost/boost/work/boost_1_50_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/address-model-64/architecture-x86/threading-multi/pthread/once.o" - no debug information available for "libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp".

warning: Could not find object file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_boost/boost/work/boost_1_50_0/bin.v2/libs/thread/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/address-model-64/architecture-x86/threading-multi/future.o" - no debug information available for "libs/thread/src/future.cpp".

warning: Could not find object file "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_boost/boost/work/boost_1_50_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/address-model-64/architecture-x86/threading-multi/error_code.o" - no debug information available for "libs/system/src/error_code.cpp".
```

I don't really know what to do. I tried downloading, compiling and installing `boost` manually and then recompile `CGAL`. However, once I tried to compile an example I got run time complain about missing `boost` libraries.

On the other hand, when trying to debug an `XCode` project (after creating it using the `-G Xcode` option for cmake) I could debug an example.

Any assistance will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with Boost when I tried installing CGAL with macports.  Then I tried the same with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and it worked like a charm.